# Remove elements of a Perl array

Tags: arrays, perl, element

Is there an easy way to remove n consecutive elements of a Perl array (thus making it shorter in length)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for the Perl builtin function [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html), which lets you pick a starting point, number of elements to remove, and an optional replacement list.

```
my @array = 0 .. 9;

my @slice = splice @array, 3, 3;

say "@slice";   # prints "3 4 5"
say "@array";   # prints "0 1 2 6 7 8 9"
say 0 + @array; # prints 7
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to remove array elements.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers indicated, `splice` works.  As an alternative approach (TIMTOWTDI, after all), if you have the upper and lower indices for the `n` consecutive elements that you want removed, then you can do it via `grep` and an array slice.  For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a=("a".."z");

#We will remove the letters "e" through "u"
my $lower=4;
my $upper=20;
print "$_\n" foreach(@a[grep{$_<$lower or $_>$upper}0..$#a]);
```

The output is:

```
a
b
c
d
v
w
x
y
z
```